# MIPS assembly: Getting "Error in line #NNN" error messages when compiling

Tags: linux, assembly, compiler-errors, mips

I am in the process of learning the MIPS assembly language but am having a hard time understanding the basics.

I am trying to run a (what I think should be simple) program but I keep getting errors on just about every line of my code.  All I want it to do is add the two values. I am running Misasim assembler, which runs through python code (maybe?)
Here is the code.

```
.data
value: .word 10, 20, 0

.text
.globl main

main: la $t0, value
      lw $t1, 0($t0)
      lw $t2, 4($t0)
      add $t3, $t1, $t2
      sw $t3, 8($t0)
```

This is what the error messages say:

```
Error in line #006: '.globl main'
Error in line #008: 'main: la $t0, value'
Error in line #009: '      lw $t1, 0($t0)'
Error in line #010: '      lw $t2, 4($t0)'
Error in line #011: '      add $t3, $t1, $t2'
Error in line #012: '      sw $t3, 8($t0)'
```

Comment: can you paste your error also

Comment: Which assembler are you using?